# Working with strings in python

Tags: python, string, irc

```
   elif data.find('PRIVMSG') != -1: 
       message = ':'.join(data.split (':')[2:]) 
       if message.lower().find('code') == -1: 
         nick = data.split('!')[ 0 ].replace(':',' ') 
         destination = ''.join (data.split(':')[:2]).split (' ')[-2] 
         function = message.split( )[0] 
         print nick + ' : ' + function
         arg = data.split( )   

         args = '' 
         for index,item in enumerate(arg) : 
              if index > 3 : 
                  if args == '': 
                      args = item 
                  else : 
                          args += ' ' + item 


 if data.find('.topic') != -1:
     nick = data.split('!')[ 0 ].replace(':','')
     for line in open('masters.txt'):
         if nick in line:
            sck.send('TOPIC ' + " " + chan + " " + args + '\r\n')
```

When I try to do something like `.topic 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` it changes the topic of the channel to `3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` instead of of the whole thing `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` I'm wondering why does it start from the 3rd string and not from the beginning? Do I need to split or strip something from the string?

Comment: What are values of `chan` and `args` ?

Comment: This isn't related to your question... but your `nick in line` check is probably not sufficient. What happens if my nick is `e`? There's probably some line in your `masters.txt` file that contains an `e`. Or, I could just choose a shorter version of your nick.

Comment: use `if '.topic' in data:` rather than `if data.find('.topic') != -1:` and it seems this code snippet is incomplete where is the definition of `args`?

Comment: How about a complete example including inputs?

Comment: @Dan D. I updated the code. And using `if '.topic' in data:` it still gets the same output it starts from number 3 instead of number 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the bug in my code.

```
  if data.find('.topic') != -1:
     nick = data.split('!')[ 0 ].replace(':','')
     for line in open('masters.txt'):
         if nick in line:
            sck.send('TOPIC ' + " " + chan + " :" + args + '\r\n')
```

this one works, I needed to add `" :"` after declaring the channel variable so it can read the data properly.

Answer (score 2):

this is the minimal example that shows the problem:

```
     data = ".topic 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"
     arg = data.split()
     args = ''
     for index,item in enumerate(arg):
          if index > 3:
              if args == '':
                  args = item
              else:
                  args += ' ' + item
     print args
```

it's all due to `if index > 3:`

Comment: so what should I change? if I change `if index > 3:` it might have problems with the other commands.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm wondering why does it start from the 3rd string and not from the beginning?*

Because thats what you told it to do. The `enumerate()` function starts indexing from 0, so index 0 corresponds to the string `'topic'`, index 1 to string `'1'` and so on. Hence, when you use the condition `if index > 3`, it will ignore the first four strings (those with indices 0, 1, 2, and 3, in your case the strings `'topic'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, and `'3'`).

Firstly, we can greatly simplify the loop to the following single line:

```
args = ' '.join(arg[4:])
```

That is, slice the `arg` list to get all entries from the fourth entry onwards, and then use the `join()` function to concatenate it into a string separated by the character `' '`.

Secondly, if you only want to remove the first entry and join the rest into the string, simply change the index to 1:

```
args = ' '.join(arg[1:])
```

If different commands need to handle the `arg` list differently, then you'll need to do this on a case-by-case basis rather than in one place:

```
arg = data.split()

if '.topic' in data:
    nick = data.split('!')[ 0 ].replace(':','')
    topic = ' '.join(arg[1:])
    for line in open('masters.txt'):
        if nick in line:
            sck.send('TOPIC %s %s\r\n' % (chan, topic))

elif '.bannick' in data:
    nick_to_ban = arg[0]
    length = arg[1]
    reason = ' '.join(arg[2:])
    for line in open('masters.txt'):
        if nick in line:
            sck.send('BAN %s %s %s %s\r\n' % (chan, nick_to_ban, length, reason))
```